# How to Install Deno on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, deno

The command I run is:

```
curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sh
```

The output is:

```
######################################################################## 100.0%
Archive:  /root/.deno/bin/deno.zip
  inflating: deno
Deno was installed successfully to /root/.deno/bin/deno
Manually add the directory to your $HOME/.bash_profile (or similar)
  export DENO_INSTALL="/root/.deno"
  export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
Run '/root/.deno/bin/deno --help' to get started
```

After this, I run **`deno`** in the terminal and it gives me an error.

Can anyone explain how to install Deno in Ubuntu properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open your terminal and run this

```
curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sh
```

username: open termianla and run  `whoami`

Now set path in .bashrc file

run `nano .bashrc`  for open file and put below code with replacing with username

```
export DENO_INSTALL="/root/.deno"
export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/home/username/.deno/bin:$PATH"
```

finally run the following command `source ~/.bashrc`

now run `deno` in your terminal

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

Installing Deno by running the following command from it's official website

```
curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sh
```

After installing it update `.bashrc` file in your profile directory:

`sudo nano ~/.bashrc`

then add these two lines in the file

```
 export DENO_INSTALL="/$HOME/.deno"
 export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

you can get this two lines from the message you get after installing deno
after

finally run the following command `source ~/.bashrc`

after that run deno by typing this command in terminal `deno`

This video explain the installation process in details [Installing deno on ubuntu](https://youtu.be/bxDOzX5ve3Q)

Comment: This works great, except that the command to edit the file should be `sudo nano ~/.bashrc` since you could easily be in a directory other than `~`

Answer (score 3):

The installer already telling you what to do after installation is finished:

> Manually add the directory to your $HOME/.bash_profile (or similar) 
>   export DENO_INSTALL="/root/.deno"
>   export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"

---

```
export DENO_INSTALL="/root/.deno" 
export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

You can just run the two lines in the terminal directly to start using it in your current terminal or just edit and add them to `$HOME/.bashrc` or `$HOME/.bash_profile` (or similar)

Comment: The installer tells you to run commands that will make it SEEM like Deno is installed. However, whenever you start a new shell, you lose the modified PATH variable.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the following commands after the installation to your bash profile. Usually `~/.bashrc` or `~./bash_profile`

```
export DENO_INSTALL="/root/.deno"
export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

(please have in mind that the above commands may change, so **always** use the values you got from the installation output)

As you can see in the output of the installation:

> Deno was installed successfully to /root/.deno/bin/deno.
>
> **Manually add the directory to your $HOME/.bash_profile** (or similar)

Once you have added those two lines you can start a new terminal, or just load your bash profile using `source` command

```
source ~/.bashrc
# or source ~/.bash_profile
```

---

If you want to install a specific version you can do so adding: `-s {version}` to that command:

```
curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sh -s v0.42.0
```

Comment: The root was /home/$USER/ in my case.

Comment: You're right, I added a note regarding that, since I used OP values.

Comment: Is it `.bashrc`, or `.bashprofile`? The installer is giving us ambiguous instructions and I think people want clarification, not more choices to make.

Comment: Both files can be used. I think people need to know all options. As a Linux user you know which bash profile you're using anyways.

Comment: It's good to note both options, but only someone who has messed with their Bash settings recently would know which one they're using. Anyone who is just using the Ubuntu defaults (or who hasn't touched them recently) would not know. The default on Ubuntu 20 is `~/.bashrc`, for the record.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue but below command worked for me:

```
curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sudo DENO_INSTALL=/usr/local sh
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure globally in ubuntu system. So first of all ,

```html
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Edit the .bashrc file and add this below code

```
export DENO_INSTALL="/root/.deno"
export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

Then just source bashrc file.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the scripts in your `bashrc` profile.

Open the `bashrc` file with any command below and add the scripts at the end of the file. After saving the file, restart your terminal.

```
# for gedit text editor
gedit ~/.bashrc
# or for GNU nano editor
nano ~/.bashrc
```

```
# deno
export DENO_INSTALL="/home/YOUR_USERNAME/.deno"
export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

Full explanation with details: [How to install Deno on Windows, Mac, and Linux Operating Systems](https://alhaqi.com/blog/install-deno-on-windows-mac-linux-operating-systems)

Answer (score 0):

You just follow the command line

```
######################################################################## 100.0%
Archive:  /root/.deno/bin/deno.zip
  inflating: deno
Deno was installed successfully to /root/.deno/bin/deno
Manually add the directory to your $HOME/.bash_profile (or similar)
  export DENO_INSTALL="/root/.deno"
  export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
Run '/root/.deno/bin/deno --help' to get started
```

It tell you that you need to go to `$HOME/.bash_profile` or similar one to add this configuration.

```
export DENO_INSTALL="/root/.deno"
export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

Here is how to add it step by step

1. `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile` or `sudo nano ~/.bashrc` (I use this because my OS is Ubuntu)
2. Copy this line into that file

```
export DENO_INSTALL="/root/.deno"
export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

Note: for those who are using Ubuntu, it is a little bit different.

```
export DENO_INSTALL="/$HOME/.deno"
export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

3. Store

- CTRL + O and Enter to save.
- CTRL + X to close the file.

4. Close the terminal, open again and type `deno --version` to check.